# Android programatically stored image has invalid format on PC

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to take a picture and save it following [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath).

The main difference is that my code is extending `Fragment`, not `Activity`. And the fact that I'm storing pictures on the private app folder instead of the public external storage.

My Code:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error occurred while creating the File:"+ex.toString());
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                    "com.eric.nativetoolkit.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException
{
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpeg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

This is basically cause every time I try to save pictures on the external Storage, AndroidStudio logcat shows the error "Error occurred while creating the File" due to permisions, I've the following permisions in my AndroidManifest.xml, and I also have a method to request it, but nothing works.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eric.nativetoolkit">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.eric.nativetoolkit.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

file_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="." />
</paths>
```

But the **main problem** is that even correctly storing pictures inside my package/files/Pictures directory, **when I try to see the image** plugging my device **onto the computer** and navigating to the folder, it shows the message (in spanish) "Can't open file":

[image]

What I can not understand is **why in my device I can correctly visualize the image**. I've tried changing format (JPG, JPEG, PNG...) but no diference.

Comment: "I try to save pictures on the external Storage it shows the error" -- what exactly is "it" in that sentence? "I've the following permisions in my AndroidManifest.xml, and I also have a method to request it, but nothing works" -- you do not need permissions to use that directory on Android 4.4+. However, you might want to add `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`.

Comment: 1.Maybe my english was a little bit poor, "every time I try to save pictures on the external Storage AndroidStudio logcat (it) shows the error." 2.I need permisions to read/write files, since write implies read, I need at least write permission. 3.Checking if that FLAG_GRANT works. But why I need that flag only for external? And where is the relation with the fact that I can not visualize my pictures on Desktop? Thanks!

Comment: "AndroidStudio logcat (it) shows the error" -- you might consider editing your question and posting the Logcat lines, including the full stack trace (if there is one). "I need permisions to read/write files, since write implies read, I need at least write permission" -- not for that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Checking if that FLAG_GRANT works. But why I need that flag only for external? And where is the relation with the fact that I can not visualize my pictures on Desktop?

You are launching a third-party camera app via `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. It has no rights to write to the location specified by your `FileProvider`-supplied `Uri`. Adding `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` tells Android that your app wishes to give write access to that location to the camera app.

Without that permission, the camera app will fail with some sort of error. You will still have a file, since you are using `File.createTempFile()` to create an unnecessary empty file before you try `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. If you look at the file size via your desktop file manager, you should see that it is 0 bytes. A 0-byte file is not a valid image, which is why the desktop cannot display it.

Comment: but if it's an empty file, it's empty for desktop and mobile device, isn't it? And I can actually see my pictures on my device folder :(

Comment: Oh god you're right, in my desktop pictures have 0KB, but how the hell can I visualize them on my device then?! :O

Comment: @Lotan: "but if it's an empty file, it's empty for desktop and mobile device, isn't it?" -- yes. "And I can actually see my pictures on my device folder :(" -- depending on the camera app, when it fails to save the picture in your requested location, it might be saving it somewhere else that is showing up in your gallery. It is also possible that your desktop file manager is caching the results of the MTP request -- if there is any sort of "refresh" option, try using that.

Comment: I've tried attaching the flag to my intent like your blog says: takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); but the result is the same, more ideas? :S

Comment: I suggested `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`, not `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`. Beyond that, use Device File Explorer in Android Studio to look at the actual filesystem of your device and see what the state of the file is. If it is 0 bytes, then the camera app cannot write there. If it is a reasonable size for a photo, then the problem lies in your desktop file manager.

Comment: oh sorry, you're right, write instead read, but even changing that, result do not change. I've checked with Android device filesystem and image has 5.1MB (seems reasonable) so I think it is Windows fault :/ I'll wait a little to see if someone else has another great idea, and if no one appears I'll mark this answer as valid, thanks CommonsWare.

Comment: results that plug and unplug the device shows the correct size (and format) of the image on windows....#facepalm and thanks again for your time, answer accepted.